# Keep session between Android WebView's loadUrl and PostUrl

Tags: java, android, webview

I use android `WebView`'s `PostUrl` to login my website, it works fine and shows homepage of my website , but after using WebView's `LoadUrl` method it ask me to login again and users will be redirected to login page. I searched a lot and found lots of answers but none of them worked for me. Here is my code :

```
 WebView wb;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_antivirus, container, false);



 CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

    wb = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Pardakht);

    wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
              return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

        }
    });


    // log in to my website successfully <~~~
    String url="http://crm.example.com/user.php?op=bG9naW4=";
    String postData="hidlogin=1&username="+username+"&password="+password+"&submit=%D9%88%D9%86%D9%87";
    wb.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));

    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

        // when i want to open new page it will be redirected to login page 
    wb.loadUrl("http://crm.example.com/customer.php?action=trafik");



    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call `wb.postUrl()` and then almost immediately after call `wb.loadUrl()`.  You have to let the first operation finish before you call the second.

When you do the second `loadUrl()`, the first `postUrl()` hasn't finished, so when `loadUrl()` is called, the `WebView` doesn't have the session cookie that would have come back with the `postUrl()` response.  The `CookieManager` code probably isn't necessary; you can take all that out.

If you need to call them one after the other, use `onPageFinished()` to determine when the post has completed so you can start the next one:

```
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url.startsWith("http://crm.example.com/user.php") {
            wb.loadUrl("http://crm.example.com/customer.php?action=trafik");
        }

    }
```

Take out all the `CookieManager`/`CookieSyncManager` stuff, then try this.

Can you get PHP code onto this server?  You should think about having a single URL that takes username/password data and displays your `customer.php?action=trafik` page.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i saw CookieManager in different answers and try it but it did not works. may you explain more where should i Set up CookieManager ? thanks again

Comment: I just noticed something about your code. I updated my answer; please take a look.

Comment: @thanks, I solved my problem before updating your answer and the way was exactly the same as you said. Thanks again.